# JSZip and cfs:collection in Meteor app

Tags: meteor, collections, zip, fs

So, Im using udondan:jszip, cfs:collection,
cfs:standard-packages and
cfs:filesystem packages in my meteor app. The problem is that I cant store my zip files in the FS.COllection. Here is some of the code  :

```
//Defining the collection
Reports = new FS.Collection('reports',{
stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem('reports', {path: "~/public"})]
});


//Trying to add a file to the collection
var zip = new JSZip();
Reports.insert(zip);
```

After running the code Im getting this error:

```
Error: DataMan constructor received data that it doesn't support
```

Is there any way to make those packages work with each other ?

Comment: Are you doing the insert on client or server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSZip` object is not a file by itself. You can generate a file from it with the [`generateAsync`](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html) function. The file type you'll want to create depends on if you want this to run on the client or server and how you want to use this file. The file types supported by both libraries are: (as per documentation, I haven't tested all these myself)

- `Blob` object (client only): `{ type: 'blob' }`
- `Uint8Array`: `{ type: 'uint8array' }`
- `ArrayBuffer`: `{ type: 'arraybuffer' }`
- `Buffer` object (server only): `{ type: 'nodebuffer' }`

So for example this should work:

```js
zip.generateAsync({ type: 'arraybuffer' })
  .then(function (content) {
    Reports.insert(content);
  });
```